# Counting days returning wrong count

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    WITH mycte AS
(
  SELECT CAST(Convert(date,getdate()) AS DATETIME) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 1
  FROM    mycte   
  WHERE   DateValue  <= ('02-28-2021)
)

--ISSUE HERE
(SELECT  SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS Count
FROM    mycte
WHERE DatePart("w",DateValue) > 1 AND DatePart("w",DateValue) < 7
group by DatePart("w",DateValue))
As WK
```

For example, I did the same for counting # of Saturdays, Sundays & Weekdays between today (24 February 2021) and end of February:

[image]

But counting today: Wednesday, Thursday & Friday should return a result of 3 not 4 per the image. I don't know why it is returning a count for a Monday when there isn't one between today and the 28th of Feb (when `selecting DatePart("w",DateValue)) for > 1 & < 7 or between 2 & 6`)

Comment: Look at the [data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95eb43d4158e0f6da421048a92206dfb) you're generating. `4` is correct as for that data as 24-26th February and 01 March are all weekdays `DateValue  <= ('02-28-2021')` should be `DateValue  < ('02-28-2021')`.

Comment: Easy solution for what you are trying to do is create a date table and join your table to it. Then all other thing become simple.

Comment: Note that if you are generating data for larger date ranges, I would suggest a Tally over a far slower rCTE.

Comment: @Lamu, it works but yet I don't get why my <= '02-28-2021' reads 03-01-2021? Thanks for your help

Comment: Also, don't use syntax like `{datetime} + {int}`; it works for the old date and time data types (`datetime`, and `smalldatetime`), but not the new ones. Use `DATEADD`.